# Liquibase: PSQLException: Unterminated dollar using SQL Changelog

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have two functions that i wanted to add to my DB using liquibase.
First one is:

```
--changeset polos:001_9
create or replace function xml_attribute_element(attribute_name varchar(255), source numeric)
    returns xml as $body$
declare

begin
    return xml_attribute_element(attribute_name, source::text);
end;
$body$
    language plpgsql immutable;
```

I got Unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$ error with it and used the way described here https://forum.liquibase.org/t/unterminated-dollar-quote-started/4553 to fix it. Now it works and looks like:

```
--changeset polos:001_9
create or replace function xml_attribute_element(attribute_name varchar(255), source numeric)
    returns xml as '
declare

begin
    return xml_attribute_element(attribute_name, source::text);
end;
'
    language plpgsql immutable;
```

The second function is:

```
--changeset polos:001_10
create or replace function xml_text_escape(source text)
    returns text as $body$
declare
    sa varchar[] := array['&', '<', '>', '"'];
    da varchar[] := array['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;'];
    t text := source;
begin
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(sa, 1) LOOP
            t := replace(t, sa[i], da[i]);
        END LOOP;
    return t;
end;
$body$
    language plpgsql immutable;
```

I cant fix it by replacing $body$ with `'` because it has `$` inside its body, so im getting same Unterminated dollar quote but in another place.

Are there any ways to fix it?

Here is a playground: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpmP1y7U4UvUhbgahuQrQc/1

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the actual changeset that runs this code (e.g. the XML file)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited. As i stated at topic name - im using SQL Changelog, so not much changed.

Comment: You need to use `splitStatements=false` - not sure how to do that in a SQL changelog in xml it would be `<changeSet splitStatements="false">`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it worked, thanks.

Declaration for SQL changelog: `--changeset name:id splitStatements:false`

Additionally:
1) If you have several functions to declare you have to do it in separate changesets;
2) You may do it without replacing '$body$' with `'`. 

Can you  please post an answer so i could mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer based on [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) comment: `splitStatements=false` can be used to solve this issue.

Declaration for SQL changelog: `--changeset name:id splitStatements:false`

Additionally:

1. If you have several functions to declare you have to do it in separate changesets;
2. You may do it without replacing '$body$' with `'` when using `splitStatements=false`.